# How to modify R code to use the Nadaraya-Watson estimator instead of the ordinary least squares estimator for a regression problem?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a sample of N observations of a response variable `Y` and two predictor variables, `X_1` and `X_2`, and I fit the standard regression model:

```
Y = beta_0 + beta_1*X_1 + beta_2*X_2 + eps.
```

I can then find the estimated coefficients, which I call `beta_hat_0`,`beta_hat_1`,`beta_hat_2`, using ordinary least squares in R with the `lm()` function. Once I have these estimated coefficients, I can make predictions of the response at any given values `x_1` and `x_2` using:

```
Y_predict = beta_hat_0 + beta_hat_1*x_1 + beta_hat_2*x_2.
```

Here is my code for this:

```
#############################################
# Define random variables
#############################################
X_1 = rnorm(N,10,2)
X_2 = rnorm(N,15,3)
eps = rnorm(N,0,1)

beta_0 = 1
beta_1 = 2
beta_2 = 2

Y = beta_0 + beta_1*X_1 + beta_2*X_2 + eps

#############################################
# Perform multiple regression
#############################################
model = lm(Y ~ X_1 + X_2)

#############################################
# Obtain OLS regression coefficients
#############################################
beta_hat_0 = model$coefficients[1]
beta_hat_1 = model$coefficients[2]
beta_hat_2 = model$coefficients[3]

#############################################
# Define a set of points at which we want to evalute the OLS estimator
#############################################
X_1_points = seq(5,15, length.out=50)
X_2_points = seq(5,25, length.out=50)

#############################################
# Evaluate the OLS estimator at the given points
#############################################
Y_predict = beta_hat_0 + beta_hat_1*X_1_points + beta_hat_2*X_2_points
```

Now I would replace the multiple regression model/OLS estimator with a nonlinear regression model/Nadaraya-Watson estimator. The Nadaraya-Watson material I've found from searching the internet seems to focus on the case of a response variable and just a single predictor, but I have two predictors.

So what do I need to do to convert the code above to use the Nadaraya Watson estimator; in particular, (i) what should be used instead of the lm() function, and (ii) how do I evaluate the Nadaray-Watson estimator at a given set of points so that I can make predictions of `Y`?

Comment: How about http://jklm.fi/regpro/man/pcf.kernesti.html?

Comment: take a look at https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/kre-ii-multmix. and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125517/what-is-nadaraya-watson-kernel-regression-estimator-for-multivariate-response. Here is also example code: https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/kre-i-kre.html#kre-i-kre-nw.